# On which Android version can I start using the geolocation feature for an application I develop?

Tags: android, geolocation, version

On which Android version can I start using the geolocation feature for an application I develop?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly you mean by "geolocation feature", but you can look at the api docs to see at which API level each feature was added.  For example, the [LocationManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html) is available since API level 1, so for all versions of Android.